# Jquery shadow box Conflict

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, joomla1.5

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Start(){
   Shadowbox.init({skipSetup: true});
   Shadowbox.open({
      content:    '/luckycement/flashxml/LuckyCement.swf',
      player:      'swf',
      title:      "",
      width:      800,
      height:      600
   })
}
//window.onload=Start;
</script>

<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/rhuk_milkyway/SpryAssets/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/rhuk_milkyway/SpryAssets/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/luckycement/plugins/content/arisexylightboxlite/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/luckycement/plugins/content/arisexylightboxlite/js/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/luckycement/plugins/content/arisexylightboxlite/js/jquery.easing.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/luckycement/plugins/content/arisexylightboxlite/js/jquery.sexylightbox.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ SexyLightbox.initialize({"dir":"\/luckycement\/plugins\/content\/arisexylightboxlite\/js\/sexyimages"}); });
  </script>

    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script-->
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {      
//alert('nida');    
    //Execute the slideShow
    slideShow();
    slideshowimg();
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    //alert($("#tabarea_r").attr('id'));

});

function slideShow() {
    //alert($('#gallery').attr('id'));
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('#gallery a').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
    $('#gallery a:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('gallery()',5000);

}

function gallery() {

    //if no IMGs have the show class, grab the first image
    var current = ($('#gallery a.show')?  $('#gallery a.show') : $('#gallery a:first'));

    //Get next image, if it reached the end of the slideshow, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption'))? $('#gallery a:first') :current.next()) : $('#gallery a:first'));   

    //Get next image caption
    var caption = next.find('img').attr('rel'); 

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('show')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
    .removeClass('show');

    //Set the opacity to 0 and height to 1px
    $('#gallery .caption').animate({opacity: 0.0}, { queue:false, duration:0 }).animate({height: '1px'}, { queue:true, duration:300 }); 

    //Animate the caption, opacity to 0.7 and heigth to 100px, a slide up effect
    $('#gallery .caption').animate({opacity: 0.7},100 ).animate({height: '100px'},500 );

    //Display the content
    $('#gallery .content').html(caption);


}
</script>
```

can anyone help me in sorting the issue? I'm using `shadowbox.js` for showing gallery images in shadowbox but it conflicts with my gallery. I'm using the function `start()` that call on index page load and run the flash file in shadowbox. But for displaying images it doesnot show shadowbox conflicts my javascript files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are conflicting because you are using two different jQuery versions. Use the latest jQuery Version only for both sexylightbox and shadowbox.